# MS ACCESS VBA - best way to change all properties values of a form's textboxes at once

Tags: vba, ms-access, textbox, global-variables

I have a form with 3 textboxs and i want to change their properties values according to some events.
My idea is to set these properties to a global form's variables in order to use them whenever i want with a function or module (this depends on your suggestion).

Assuming that i want to change all textboxs.enabled property by pressing a button
and i want to change another different property if needed in the future (like bordercolor),
my example is this:
in the form VBA,

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Private Const AllTxtboxes = *** all txtboxes ***
```

in the VBA button

```
Private Sub button1_Click()
AllTxtboxes.enabled = True
End sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no such global *change this property* capability. You can loop through the controls on the form to change each one individually to a specified value, or put a reference to them in an array and loop through that to do so, but you can't do it all at once with a single expression as you're asking.

Comment: Maybe is good to assign all txtboxs.name to an array in a function and call this function in a subroutine.. but i dont know how to assign to an array all the txtboxs names..

Comment: You don't assign the *txtbox names*. You assign the textbox itself to an element in the array. There are examples in other posts here of doing that, if you search for `[vba] control array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop trough all controls and identify those you want to change. The problem is that each control type got their own properties, so you need to make sure you are in the right one.

And for that, there is a property common to all controls named `Tag`

There, you can specify a value and check it. It's really helpful to select only what you want.

I made a simple form with 6 textboxes:

[image]

Note that in design view, properties panel at right, tab **others**, last property is `Tag` (sometimes it comes as *aditional info* or something like it).

There, I typed 99 but only on textboxes 2, 4 and 6, because those are the textboxes I want to handle (that would be kind of your *array of textboxes*)

I added a command button to change forecolor of those textboxes to red when clicked. My code is:

```
Private Sub CMD_CHANGE_FONT_COLOR_Click()
Me.Painting = False
Dim MyControl As Control
Dim MyTxt As TextBox


For Each MyControl In Me.Controls
    If MyControl.Tag = 99 Then
        'we set MyTxt to MyControl so we can use Intellisense, not really needed, but it makes coding easier
        Set MyTxt = MyControl
        MyTxt.ForeColor = vbRed
        Set MyTxt = Nothing
    End If
Next MyControl

Me.Painting = True

End Sub
```

When the form loads, you will see:

[image]

But after click on command button, the forecolor of those 3 textboxes will be red:

[image]

There you go. So everytime you want to do something with that *array of textboxes*, you can use this code to loop and change the properties you want.